# What is the best way to append to /etc/hosts within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

Unfortunately, Docker does not persist the /etc/hosts file between RUN commands in Dockerfiles

Please recommend the best way to append to /etc/hosts within Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best not to do this, mainly because you are tying the image to your network. Instead, use the `--add-host` flag to `docker run` to add entries e.g:

```
docker run --add-host test:127.0.0.1 nginx
```

Comment: In that case, what should i do if I have around 15 enteries??  Also, what you think about the tool named mungehosts https://github.com/hiteshjasani/nim-mungehosts